# How debug IBM db2 9.5 function

Tags: function, debugging, db2

I created a function and now I need to debug it.

How can I do this?

I'm using IBM db2 9.5 version

My function declaration:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TESTE (v_id INTEGER, v_calnum VARCHAR(16), reportdate TIMESTAMP, enddate TIMESTAMP)

RETURNS BIGINT
SPECIFIC TESTE
DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION READS SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
[...]
RETURN VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to debug inlined functions, which yours would be, because, as the name suggests, they become a part of the SQL statement that calls them.

You can debug *compiled* routines using IBM Data Studio. [More info in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0020476.html?lang=en).

PS. The link is for version 10.5, but there was some debugging support in 9.5 as well. Any particular reason you're not using the latest version?

Comment: Hi Mustaccio.  Thanks for your reply. I was looking for a solution other than IBM Data Studio. I have security rules where I can't install any program. About the version, we are studying the upgrade for the newest version.

Comment: How is it chosen which programs can be installed and which can't?( DB2 was apparently okay to install, so some installs are allowed.) Seems odd, and risky, that debugging facilities are not allowed but it's allowed to create programming (i.e., functions and procs). Management should review those restrictions.